# Flex chart labels way too small, how to resize axis?

Tags: apache-flex, charts

So I have a Flex bar chart that resizes dynamically, and if I have only a few items, the height shrinks and the horizontal axis and label shrink along with it.  If the height of the chart is small enough, the label shrink down to practically nothing.

How can I enforce a minimum height for the axis itself?  Or even a minimum font size for the labels?

I've tried setting the font size on the axis renderer and the axis label renderer and Flex still wants to resize the labels how it wants.

Answer (score 0):

put a minHeight on the container I believe...  but mostly just wanted to point out Axiis to you...