# Flex / Adobe Air - Chart legend/Axis fontsize too small

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I'm adding a chart to my AIR App. Here is how:

```
    private function CountersChart(container:VGroup):void {

        var arr:Array = [];
        var dt:Date = new Date();
        var counters:Counters = Constants.srv.getCounters(dt.fullYear, dt.month);
        var goals:ArrayCollection = Constants.srv.getGoals();

        var index:int = 0;
        var found:Boolean = false;
        var now:Date = new Date();

        while (!found) {
            var goal:Goals = goals[index];
            if (now.month+1==goal.month && now.fullYear==goal.year) {
                found=true;
                break;
            } else
                index++;
        }

        arr.push({label:"Calls", x:"Calls",  y:counters.phone, y1:goals[index].calls});
        arr.push({label:"Text", x:"Text", y:counters.sms, y1:goals[index].sms});
        arr.push({label:"Email", x:"Email", y:counters.email, y1:goals[index].emails});
        arr.push({label:"Marketing Tools", x:"Marketing Tools", y:counters.marketing, y1:goals[index].sendMarketingTools});
        arr.push({label:"Meetings", x:"Meetings", y:counters.meeting, y1:goals[index].meetings});
        arr.push({label:"Home Presentations Invites", x:"Home Presentations Invites", y:counters.homePresentationInvite, y1:goals[index].homePresentations});
        arr.push({label:"Business Presentation Invites", x:"Business Presentation Invites", y:counters.businessPresentationInvite, y1:goals[index].businessPresentations});

        // Create a column chart object
        var stackedColumnChart:ColumnChart = new ColumnChart();
        stackedColumnChart.dataProvider = arr;
        stackedColumnChart.showDataTips = true;
        stackedColumnChart.dataTipFunction = myDataTipFunction;
        stackedColumnChart.percentWidth   = 100;

        // Set the horizontal axix category
        var xAxis:CategoryAxis = new CategoryAxis();
        xAxis.categoryField = "x";
        stackedColumnChart.horizontalAxis = xAxis;

        // ColumnSet.series is an array which contains
        // an array of ColumnSeries objects.
        var columnSet:ColumnSet = new ColumnSet();
        columnSet.type = "stacked";

        // Each item in seriesDetails becomes a different segment of
        // a column in the stacked chart i.e. each item represents a series.
        var seriesDetails:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
            {YField:"y", DisplayName:"Actual"},
            {YField:"y1", DisplayName:"Planned"},
        ]);

        // Create a ColumnSeries, and an array to be
        // populated with dynamically generated columnSeries objects
        var columnSeries:ColumnSeries;
        var seriesArray:Array = new Array();
        var xr:AxisRenderer = new AxisRenderer();
        xr.setStyle("fontSize",40);
        //columnSeries.verticalAxis = xr;
        // Generate an array of ColumnSeries objects
        // which are then be applied to the ColumnSet series.
        for(var i:int = 0; i < seriesDetails.length; i++){
            columnSeries = new ColumnSeries();
            columnSeries.yField = seriesDetails[i].YField;
            columnSeries.displayName = seriesDetails[i].DisplayName;
            columnSeries.setStyle("fill",fillsArray[i]);
            seriesArray.push(columnSeries);
        }
        columnSet.series = seriesArray;

        // c.series could take an array of column sets
        // for displaying mixed charts i.e. c.series = [columnSet1, columnSet2];
        stackedColumnChart.series = [columnSet];    
        //stackedColumnChart.showAllDataTips();
        stackedColumnChart.showDataTips = true;
        stackedColumnChart.id = "chart";
        var legend:Legend = new Legend();
        legend.direction = "horizontal";
        legend.setStyle("fontSize",30);
        legend.dataProvider = stackedColumnChart;

        stackedColumnChart.setStyle("horizontalAxisRenderers", xr);
        stackedColumnChart.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,function(event){return});

        //Add chart to the display list. 
        container.addElement(stackedColumnChart);
        container.addElement(legend);               
    }
```

The result draws the chart nicely BUT: The font size of the legend and the x/y axis are soooo small, Can't even read them.

I've tried to set the legend.setStyle("fontSize",fs) or to set the legend minHeight (as suggested here: [Flex chart labels way too small, how to resize axis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5835147/flex-chart-labels-way-too-small-how-to-resize-axis)

But to no avail :-(

How can I modify the font size for them?

Thanks

Comment: please see answer below and accept if it work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide the css for LegendItem class and ColumnChart class, and then it will pick up the style for it:

```
<fx:Style>
    @namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";
    @namespace mx "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx";

    mx|LegendItem
    {
        fontSize:20;
    }
    mx|ColumnChart
    {
        fontSize:15;
    }

</fx:Style>
```

Providing setStyle to Legend does not work.

Please let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Thank you Randhir. I applied the Style to the App. But alas.. no difference. Do I need to do something in the code as well?

Comment: Are you keeping this code in same mxml file where you have chart component declared ? You also need to validate whether the same css is already declared anywhere in your css file or not. There is no change in code you just need to apply css in the mxml file where you have added chart component or within the global css file.